# Getting lowest value in array or random value if all is the same?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like so

```
Array
(
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
)
```

the key 5 and key 6 are user id's. the value 0 for both the keys are the number of posts they have.

How do i obtain the user with the lowest post and if there are more than 1 user with the same/lowest post, select one by random.

Thank you

Comment: The title is somehow confusing as you want to get the **USER** with the lowest post value or random **USER** if the values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`min()`](https://www.php.net/min) for the lowest value in the array and [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random entry out of the array.

```
$yourArr = array(4, 4, 3, 5);

$lowestEntry = min($yourArr);
$duplicateEntries = array_keys($yourArr, $lowestEntry);

echo (count($duplicateEntries) > 1)?$yourArr[array_rand($duplicateEntries, 1)]:$lowestEntry;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your array is `$arr`

```
$mini = min($arr);
$user = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
    if ($val == $mini){
        // find the user with minimum value
        $user[] = $key;
    }
}
// print the user with minimum value
echo array_rand($user, 1).' '.$mini;
```

Comment: That will not select random key, but will select first key (with minimum value)

Comment: Yeah. But any of the answer would be okay. Just modify the code in the for statement

Comment: No, _random_ is not the same as _first every time_. Random means that it will be selected randomly each time when script is executed